# How to track in logs requests from same user?

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, config, haproxy, tracking

I want to be able to link various requests that are coming from same client (browser). I came with adding header based on cookie:

```
backend servers
        description My backend

        http-request set-header Request-Id %[req.cook(AspNet.Session),sha1,hex]

        server srv_01 127.0.0.1:5000
```

This is going to be used only for debug purposes when I want to find what user was doing. Should I be worried about performance? My cookie is around 300 bytes. There are also other hash functions (like `xxh64` or `wt6`). Does it makes sense to use it?

Debian Buster, haproxy 2.2, ASP.Net Core as backend server.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, If it related to your debug environment, I think is not bad for performance, but consider this, every sidecar added, has its own overhead to the response time, You can follow one of the following scenarios:

1. write a action filter to log request/response/userInfo [ActionFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0)
2. use some event-based patterns. this approach has less overhead on the response time because the logging will be processed separately and independent of the current request threat.

but I'm quite sure, there are other patterns that can be used to logging requests and user info.